# SQL Show value that appears more times and how many times

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to show the value that appears more times from a movies table.

For example:

```
movie_id, tag_id, score
1         1       4
1         3       5
2         1       3
3         2       4
3         3       5
```

Result:

```
tag_id, times
1       2
3       2
2       1
```

That table has the following columns: {movie-id, tag-id, score}.

How I can retrieve the tag-id that appears more times and how many times?

I've tried the following but it shows the same number for each tag-id:

```
SELECT tagId, COUNT(tagId) AS ocurrence FROM scores GROUP BY tagId ORDER BY ocurrence DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean "appears"?

Comment: I've edited it with an example.

Comment: tag your dbms too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT TAGID, COUNT(TAGID) 
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY TAGID
ORDER BY COUNT(TAGID) 

--or you could do a having clause where COUNT(TAG-ID) > 1
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? In each tagId appears the same ocurrences.

Comment: Yes this works in my environment which is SSMS. If you're using another DBMS, there may be some syntax differences. However, if you're continuing to get the same tagid's perhaps you should look at your data in the table and verify there are different tag ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tagId, COUNT(tagId) FROM scores GROUP BY (tagID) HAVING COUNT(tagId) >= ALL 
    (SELECT COUNT(tagId) FROM scores GROUP BY (tagId))
```

This will also work.